# Flutter - print querysnapshot on firebase document does not work

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the function below, I want to get all the records in a collection named 'contexts'.

But, when I ask to print each record, I get nothing, not even an empty field or a null.

On the console, it is like if I have never ask for print.

I do not understand why.

```
Future getAllContextInFirebaseV1() async {

  CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
  .doc((FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid))
  .collection('contexts');

  QuerySnapshot contextsQuery = await ref
      .get();

  contextsQuery.docs.forEach((document) {

  print(document['context_Name']);

  });
  
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: share you DB image. what do you mean records. documents snapshot?

Comment: Yes, by records, I mean document. pictures added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contextsQuery.docs` is a list of snapshots. You actually need to call `.data()` on each document to access the data ('context_Name').

So instead of

```dart
print(document['context_Name']);
```

you should have

```dart
print((document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['context_Name']);
```

Note that the document has other properties on it like exists, id, reference, ...

But wait, are you sure that there are documents inside the *contexts* subcollection on the current user? Because chances are `contextsQuery.size` could be zero, so forEach doesn't get called.

If yes, are you sure that the collection names are correct?

Comment: I have tried and I am getting this error message "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'."
I have a first collection Users, then contexts. In the collection contexts, I have several documents. Those are the ones I must get the info

Comment: oh okay yes we need to type the return of `data()` as Map, let me update the answer

Comment: I have tried but print does not display any document. I do not understand.
usually, I do the code below, but here I can't as I use a function.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamBuilder(
   stream:
       FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('contexts')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,

Comment: okay add `print(contextsQuery.size);` just before the line of `contextsQuery.docs.forEach...`, let's see if it will print a valid value.

Comment: done. But nothing is displayed. I have never seen that so far. I am using print usually to check my code and the values return. But here I do not understand why print is not working.

Comment: I would prefer to share screenshot if you don't mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245738/discussion-between-laurent-thomas-and-obumuneme-nwabude).